# Android functional test input to EditText missing randomly

Tags: android, android-testing

I am writing a functional test for my activity which has EditText and TextView . The TextView changes based on user input from EditText. When I run my test the EditText doesn't get my input sometimes, and the test fails as a result.

The following is the minimal version of my tests which still gives me the same problem.

```
public class MainActivityTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MainActivity> {

    private MainActivity mainActivity;

    public MainActivityTest() {
        super(MainActivity.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        mainActivity = getActivity();
    }

    public void testEditTextOne() {
        final EditText e = (EditText) mainActivity.findViewById(R.id.edit_message);

        getInstrumentation().runOnMainSync(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                e.requestFocus();
            }
        });
        getInstrumentation().waitForIdleSync();
        getInstrumentation().sendStringSync("120");
        getInstrumentation().waitForIdleSync();

        assertEquals("120", e.getText().toString());
    }

    public void testEditTextTwo() {
        final EditText e = (EditText) mainActivity.findViewById(R.id.edit_message);

        getInstrumentation().runOnMainSync(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                e.requestFocus();
            }
        });
        getInstrumentation().waitForIdleSync();
        getInstrumentation().sendStringSync("130");
        getInstrumentation().waitForIdleSync();

        assertEquals("130", e.getText().toString());
    }
}
```

When I run the above tests, most of the times, `testEditTextOne()` would pass and `testEditTextTwo()` would fail. Sometimes, both tests fail.

`testEditTextTwo()` pass if I run it separately, but even that sometimes fail if I run it repeatly for about 10 times.

I am running tests with 'Android Instrumentation Tests' on Android Studio 1.1.0, and don't use any third party testing frameworks.

I've just started with Android, so I don't know if I am causing some kind of race condition. Please explain me what is causing this strange behavior.